# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_2: expected shape=(1, None, 256), found shape=[64, 14, 256]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to generate some text based on a list of company names passed as training data. The tutorial I am following is https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation#process_the_text.

When I try to fit my model I get

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_2: expected shape=(1, None, 256), found shape=[64, 14, 256]

My dataset dimensions are `<BatchDataset shapes: ((64, 14), (64, 14)), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32)>`

To create my model I used the following code,

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64
vocab_size = 62
embedding_dim = 256
rnn_units = 2048

def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),
        # tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')),
        tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
    ])
    return model

# model  = build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

My Model summary looks like this.

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (1, None, 256)            15872     
_________________________________________________________________
gru_2 (GRU)                  (1, None, 1024)           3938304   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (1, None, 62)             63550     
=================================================================
Total params: 4,017,726
Trainable params: 4,017,726
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: You created your model with batch size = 1 burned in. The tutorial you linked uses batch size 64 `tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None]),` where batch_size is 64. Can you include your code where you create your model?

Comment: By Experimenting I changed the BATCH_SIZE parameter to 1 and it seems to be working now. I think the model was expecting an input with a batch dimension of 1 and instead it was being given an input with batch dimension 64. Everything is working now.